# List of well known Claim Type

Tags: adfs

I'm building a single sign-on service using ADFS. I can't find a complete list of claim types (Ex: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier).

There are some partial lists on Microsoft's website and the Oasis wiki pages. Does anyone know where I can find a comprehensive list?

Comment: [ClaimTypes Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes_members.aspx), which was located by internet search for "ADFS claim types"

Comment: Thanks for your help. As I previously mentioned, I found the same list on Microsoft's website and another on Oasis's website. I didn't know if a more comprehensive one exists or if that's it.

Comment: define comprehensive- you can add any claimtype you want with ADFS, more important is what claimtypes you want vs your ADFS will allow

Answer (score 1):

The **Information Card Foundation** (ICF) was maintaining such a list at: http://wiki.informationcard.net/index.php?title=Claim_Catalog#Well_Known_Claims

Since informationcard slowly disappeared the site isn't available anymore, too.
Luckily you can still access it, thanks to archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20140823181452/http://wiki.informationcard.net:80/index.php?title=Claim_Catalog#Well_Known_Claims

You may also refer to the **OASIS Identity Metasystem Interoperability Version 1.0**:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/imi/identity/v1.0/os/identity-1.0-spec-os.html#_Toc229451870
(Although that's probably the OASIS source you already discovered)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your ADFS instance [exposes a URL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-openId-connect-with-ad-fs#to-modify-the-app) with the well-known configuration.
While perhaps not an exhaustive list it would be the default set of ADFS claim types and a great place to start.

Answer (score -1):

You can also have a look at [my site](https://www.rcfed.com/Message/Claimtypelist), where I have collected those often used.